# VBA: how to pass a string containing a variable defined in another subroutine?

Tags: vba, excel

I am stuck at an excel VBA programming problem. I have one sheet containing a list of ids (column A) with 2 other columns (level1 (column B) and level2 (column C)) indicating their categories. What I need to do is to, in VBA, loop through a list of subgroups (group1, group2, group3) such that each time a filter string is applied on level1 and level2, for example: `group1 = And(B&CStr(r) = abc, C&CStr(r) = 123), group2 = And(B&Cstr(r) = xyz, C&CStr(r) = 789)`, where variable "`r`" is the row number defined in the main subroutine.

Since for each group, I will need to apply the same filter to each row in the sheet and save the ids satisfying the condition to an array, I placed the filters in a separate **FUNCTION** which returns the filter string when a group is selected. The problem I have is that the variable "r" is defined and only assigned a value in the main subroutine and so I get a "variable not defined" error in the function that defines the filters for each group. If I set everything in the filter including CStr(r) in double quotes in the function, the "r" will not be used as variable and NOT be assigned a row number dynamically in the main subroutine.

Is there a way to define the filter string in an abstract way and let value of "r" be assigned dynamically only in the main subroutine?

Here is an example of the function code:

```
Function getsectorlist_example() As Dictionary
Set sectorlist = New Dictionary
categoryname = "Group1"
level1 = "= " & """ABC"""
level2 = "= " & """123"""
level3 = "and(F" & CStr(r) & level1 & ", G" & CStr(r) & level2 & ")"
filter = level3
sectorlist.Add categoryname, filter
categoryname = "Group2"
level1 = "= " & """XYZ"""
level2 = "= " & """789"""
level3 = "and(F" & CStr(r) & level1 & ", G" & CStr(r) & level2 & ")"
filter(2) = level3
sectorlist.Add categoryname, filter`enter code here`
Set getsectorlist = sectorlist
End Function
```

Here is an example for the main code:

```
Function Main_example(sectorfilter As Variant) As Dictionary

Dim ws_alldata As Worksheet
Dim seclist As Dictionary
Dim values(2) As Double
Dim r As Long, currentIDs As String, wgt As Double, ctr As Double
Dim fullfilter As String

Set ws_alldata = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set seclist = New Dictionary

r = 2
currentIDs = ws_alldata.Cells(r, 2)
  wgt = ws_alldata.Cells(r, 3)
  ctr = ws_alldata.Cells(r, 4)


ws_alldata.Activate

While Len(ws_alldata.Cells(r, 1)) > 0


    fullfilter = sectorfilter
    If Eval(fullfilter) = True Then

        If seclist.Exists(currentIDs) Then
            values(0) = wgt + seclist(currentIDs)(0)
            values(1) = ctr + seclist(currentIDs)(1)
            values(2) = values(1) / values(0)

            seclist.Remove (currentIDs)
        Else
            values(0) = wgt
            values(1) = ctr
            values(2) = values(1) / values(0)

        End If

        seclist.Add currentIDs, values

    End If

  r = r + 1
  currentIDs = ws_alldata.Cells(r, 2)
  wgt = ws_alldata.Cells(r, 3)
  ctr = ws_alldata.Cells(r, 4)

Wend

Set getseclistinsector = seclist

End Function
```

Comment: It's probably just a simple case of "pass the variable `r` as a parameter to the function", but if you post the code for the function, and the relevant part of the main code, we can probably give you a specific answer.

Comment: Function getsectorlist_example() As Dictionary
    Set sectorlist = New Dictionary
    categoryname = "Group1"
    level1 = "= " & """ABC"""
    level2 = "= " & """123"""
    level3 = "and(F" & CStr(r) & level1 & ", G" & CStr(r) & level2 & ")"
    filter = level3
    sectorlist.Add categoryname, filter
    categoryname = "Group2"
    level1 = "= " & """XYZ"""
    level2 = "= " & """789"""
    level3 = "and(F" & CStr(r) & level1 & ", G" & CStr(r) & level2 & ")"
    filter(2) = level3
    sectorlist.Add categoryname, filter
    Set getsectorlist = sectorlist
End Function

Comment: Sorry, there seems a limit on characters. Not sure how to control the format.

Comment: Below is the part in main code:     r = 2
    currentIDs = ws_alldata.Cells(r, 2)
      wgt = ws_alldata.Cells(r, 3)
      ctr = ws_alldata.Cells(r, 4)

    
    ws_alldata.Activate
    
    While Len(ws_alldata.Cells(r, 1)) > 0
        

        fullfilter = sectorfilter
        If Eval(fullfilter) = True Then
            
            If seclist.Exists(currentIDs) Then
                values(0) = wgt + seclist(currentIDs)(0)
                values(1) = ctr + seclist(currentIDs)(1)
                values(2) = values(1) / values(0)

Comment: [Edit the code into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40683891/edit) instead of putting it in the comments.

Comment: Can't you just use an `Array` and then use `For Loop` with `LBound() To UBound()`?

Comment: Niclas, I am not sure I understand how you would propose to use Array in this example. I would need to define filter rule with respect to the group selected. And then the rule itself is updated by row number, just like we copy function to all rows in excel. Currently the best way I could think of is to define rule object/class module.